# Tizen on screen keyboard (entry component) text cutoff

Tags: c, user-interface, tizen

I am creating my first tizen app, for a watch.  I have started with the SettingUI sample code, and have added a 'name' item to the genlist, which I want to push a view where I enter my name.  I will enter my name using an entry (on screen keyboard) component.

I see the keyboard in the emulator but the "A short text" text is partially cutoff at the top and left of the screen.  It's as if the text flows in a SQUARE shape, but should flow in a CIRCLE shape.  (But I do have a circle surface applied to the naviframe).  If I switch the entry to single line (not multiline) then the text is actually hidden behind the keyboard).  And the naviframe is inside the conformant.

Can anyone explain how I would make the entry (keyboard) text appear properly onscreen?

```
void _setting_name_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info EINA_UNUSED)
{
    appdata_s *ad = data;
    Evas_Object *naviframe = ad->naviframe;
    Elm_Object_Item *nf_it = NULL;

    /* Unhighlight Item */
    elm_genlist_item_selected_set((Elm_Object_Item *)event_info, EINA_FALSE);

    // Create a keyboard (entry) and add to naviframe
    Evas_Object *entry;
    entry = elm_entry_add(naviframe);
    elm_entry_entry_set(entry, "A short text.");

    // Push the entry onto the naviframe to show it
    nf_it = elm_naviframe_item_push(naviframe, _("Slider"), NULL, NULL, entry, "empty");

    // Set the callback of the naviframe when layout popped off
    elm_naviframe_item_pop_cb_set(nf_it, _setting_name_finished_cb, ad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size_hint` property with ui containers.

```
void _setting_name_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info EINA_UNUSED)
{
    appdata_s *ad = data;
    Evas_Object *naviframe = ad->naviframe;
    Elm_Object_Item *nf_it = NULL;

    /* Unhighlight Item */
    elm_genlist_item_selected_set((Elm_Object_Item *)event_info, EINA_FALSE);

    // Create a Box
    Evas_Object *box;
    box = elm_box_add(naviframe);
    evas_object_show(box);

    // Create a keyboard (entry) and add to box
    Evas_Object *entry;
    entry = elm_entry_add(box);
    elm_entry_entry_set(entry, "A short text.");

    evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(entry, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
    evas_object_size_hint_align_set(entry, EVAS_HINT_FILL, 0.5);
    evas_object_size_hint_padding_set(entry, 50, 50, 30, 240);
    elm_entry_single_line_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);
    elm_entry_scrollable_set(entry, EINA_TRUE);
    evas_object_show(entry);

    elm_box_pack_end(box, entry);

    // Push the entry onto the naviframe to show it
    nf_it = elm_naviframe_item_push(naviframe, _("Slider"), NULL, NULL, box, "empty");

    // Set the callback of the naviframe when layout popped off
    elm_naviframe_item_pop_cb_set(nf_it, _setting_finished_cb, ad);
}
```